# Generic Method Won't Recognise Generic Type When Passing It as a Parameter

Tags: android, generics

I'm trying to generify dynamic fragment instantiation:

```
private <F extends Fragment> void addFragment(F fragment) {
    fragment.setArguments(new Bundle());
    FragmentTransaction tx = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    tx.add(R.id.container, fragment);
    tx.submit();
}
```

However, the compiler rejects `tx.add(R.id.container, fragment)` because there's no method signature for `add(int, F)`!

How do I make the add() method understand that F is indeed a Fragment?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is because you imported a wrong `Fragment` in your class that it is not compatible with the fragment argument of the add method.

since you used a `getFragmentManager()` that means you need to use the non support library for the fragment to enable the generic to be compatible with the add method.

Make sure that your import is like this:

```
import android.app.Fragment;
```

Comment: Thanks. When is it, and when is it not, a good idea to use the non support library?

Comment: Depends on you if you are targeting newer device then use the non support else if you are targeting older device then use support library